# Click events on desktop

Tags: aframe

Im using `aframe` for a different purpose than VR. Im using it to show a 3d model where the user can rotate the model, zoom in, out, and inspect various parts of the device on click.

Im using `aframe-orbit-controls-component-2` component to make the camera rotate around the device model.

How do I detect mouse clicks on specific parts of the device(I already have these parts with ids, I just need to detect mouse clicks on them) without needing the camera to be focused on said part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mouse by setting the `cursor`s attribute `rayOrigin: mouse`:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
....
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/206o3s9t/) - the console will log the elements which are clicked